# Updating a row using a ROWTYPE variable in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Let's say I'm writing a Postgres PSQL script in which I fetch a rowtype variable from the DB:

```
DECLARE    
  m_bal  Balances%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  SELECT INTO m_bal *
  FROM Balances
  WHERE Balances.id = m_acct.id AND Balances.currency = _currency;
...
```

and then I'd like to update one or more values depending on more complex logic and save it to the database:

```
UPDATE Balances
SET ROW = m_bal
WHERE id = m_bal.id;
```

only this doesn't work and I'm getting nowhere after an hour of googling, I'm getting a general idea that Postgres doesn't support this, but having a definitive answer "no" would also be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but that won't work.

While you can use whole-row references in `SELECT` lists, `UPDATE` only allows column names or parenthized column lists in the `SET` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Not whole row, though you can update each columns separately (as usually update, something like this):

```
create table test(
col1 text,
col2 int
);

insert into test
values
('asd4', 4),
('asd5', 5),
('asd6', 6) ;


do $$
declare
    m_bal  test%ROWTYPE;
begin
    SELECT INTO m_bal *
    FROM test
    WHERE test.col2 = 5;

    UPDATE test
    SET 
    col1 = m_bal.col1,
    col2 = m_bal.col2
    WHERE col2 = 6;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```